# Enviar pdf por whatsapp

Tags: android

Quiero enviar un pdf creado en la app por whatsapp en un android version 13 y con

android {
compileSdkVersion 33

buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

}

defaultConfig {

minSdkVersion 26

targetSdkVersion 33

}

Lo que ocurre es que whatsapp se abre e inicia la conversación con le teléfono dado pero no hace nada para mandar el pdf. El pdf lo crear bien y además he intentado con éxito enviarlo directamente por whatsapp desde  whatsapp.

Para pedir permiso:

```
checkExternalStoragePermission();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
} else {
     crearpdf();
}


 private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        crearpdf();
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo es el siguiente:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void crearpdf() {
    try {
        Document document = new Document( PageSize.LETTER );
        String ARCHIVO = "Recibo_" + gmportadores + ".pdf";
        File destinoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), CARPETA);
        if (!destinoPath.exists()) { destinoPath.mkdir(); }
        File pdfSubDir = new File(destinoPath + File.separator + RECIBOS);
        if (!pdfSubDir.exists()) { pdfSubDir.mkdir(); }
        File nombre_completo = new File( pdfSubDir + File.separator + ARCHIVO);
        if (!nombre_completo.exists()) { nombre_completo.delete(); }
        PdfWriter pdfwrite = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( nombre_completo.toString() ) );

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault() );
        Date date = new Date();
        String swfecha = dateFormat.format( date );

        // Creamos el documento para escribirlo
        document.open();
        document.addTitle( "Recibo Portador Cristo de las Injurias" );

        XMLWorkerHelper xmlWorkerHelper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

        String htmlToPdf = "<html>\n" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                ".Verdana {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                ".Arial {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "  <table width=\"545\" height=\"316\" border=\"10\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"198\" rowspan=\"2\" align=\"center\"><font color=\"#130f40\"><h1>Recibo</h1></font></td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"69\"><font color=\"#990000\"><strong>Fecha</strong></font></td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"211\" align=\"center\"><font color=\"#00a8ff\"><strong>" + swfecha + "</strong></font></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"69\"><strong><font color=\"#990000\">Importe</font></strong></td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"211\" align=\"center\"><font color=\"#00a8ff\"><strong>" + cuotatext.getText().toString() + "</strong></font></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td colspan=\"3\"  align=\"center\"><h1><font color=\"#ff5252\" class=\"Verdana\">Stmo. Cristo de las Injurias</font></h1></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td colspan=\"3\">\n" +
                "         <div align=\"justify\"><h3><font color=\"#00a8ff\" class=\"Arial\"><strong><em>" + gmportadores + "</em></strong></font></h3></div>\n" +
                "     <div align=\"justify\"><h3>   Como portador del Stmo. Cristo de las Injurias ha abonado la cantidad arriba indicada en concepto de couta voluntaria del año: " + gmanno + "</h3></div>\n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </table>\n" +
                " </body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";
        try {
            xmlWorkerHelper.parseXHtml( pdfwrite, document, new StringReader(htmlToPdf) );
            document.close();

            try {
                document.close();
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                String numTelefono = "34" + gmtelefonos;
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(nombre_completo.toString()));
                intent.putExtra("jid", numTelefono + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //numero telefonico sin prefijo "+"!
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                    .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                    });
            alertDialogCopiaError.show();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
        alertDialogCopiaError.show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
        alertDialogCopiaError.show();
    }
}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?
Gracias

---

Esto es lo que me sale en el LogCat:

```
2023-05-04 08:36:24.286 1405-8545/? E/BinderTransaction: Binder proc file not exist.
```

Asi lo he preparado y sigue igual:

```
File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/PDF"));
                File file = new File(dir, ARCHIVO);
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", file, ARCHIVO);
                String numTelefono = "34" + gmtelefonos;
                final Intent compartir = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        //.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, destinatarios)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Se adjunta archivo")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                        .putExtra("jid", numTelefono + "@s.whatsapp.net")
                        .setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                        .setType("application/pdf");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartir, "Compartir PDF"));
```

Comment: Ya revisaste en donde se puede generar el problema? que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Tienes errores que podría considerarse importantes, por ejemplo cierras el documento y luego tratas de cerrarlo, te sugiero agregar más información a tu pregunta, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

creo que estas intentando compartir tu archivo directamente desde la ruta de tu archivo con un uri pero deberia usar fileProvider

intenta crando tu uri asi :

```
 File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF"));
 file = new File(dir, nombreArchivo);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PdfView.this, PdfView.this.getPackageName() + ".provider", file, nombreArchivo);

final Intent compartir = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, destinatarios)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF")
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Se adjunta archivo")
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                            .setType("application/pdf");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartir, "Compartir PDF"))
```

;

Ademas en tu manifes agrega esto:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

y crea una carpeta en res llamada xml, dentro crearas un xml resourse File con el nombre provider_paths.xml y debe quedar asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Lo probare, Pero tambien me he dado cuenta que la app no tiene Permisos concedidos en la informacion de la aplicacion. Como lo puedo hacer

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, marcala como respuesta aceptada
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

OK Muchas Gracias ya lo he solucionado, con la respuesta de Davis Estrada y una pequeña modificación:

```
//File dir = new File((Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) +  CARPETA));
//File file = new File(dir, ARCHIVO);
//Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", file, ARCHIVO);
  Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", nombre_completo);
```

Donde nombre_completo es :

```
String ARCHIVO = "Recibo_" + gmportadores + ".pdf";
File destinoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), CARPETA);
File pdfSubDir = new File(destinoPath + File.separator + RECIBOS);
File nombre_completo = new File( pdfSubDir + File.separator + ARCHIVO);
```

Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Esto no es un foro. Esta está bien pero tu anterior "respuesta" no es una respuesta. Si quieres dar más información debes EDITAR TU PREGUNTA!! Por favor, cíñete a las reglas que para eso están. SO no muestra las respuestas en el orden que se ponen si no por puntuación, lo que hace que con el tiempo tu "respuesta" anterior vaya a desaparecer del sitio que ocupa actualmente! Y en SO no estamos para ayudarte solo a ti, si no a cualquier otra persona que tenga un problema similar! Pides ayuda, te la damos... ahora haz que otros puedan beneficiarse del tiempo invertido por todos!